# How to use setLabelFor with radiobuttons in java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

```
JPanel panel1 =new JPanel();

panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(black,"panel1");

Jlabel radiobuttons=new JLabel("Radio Buttons:");

JRadioButton b1=new JRadioButton("Yes");
 radiobuttons.setLabelFor(b1);

JRadioButton b=new JRadioButton("NO");
 radiobuttons.setLabelFor(b2);
```

Here I added these two radiobuttons to button group also and I am using setLabelFor() for radio buttons but ScreenReader is reading only panel1 Yes and Panel1 No, but not reading Panel1 Radio Buttons Yes and ading Panel1 Radio Buttons NO what to do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't share a label for two components so it doesn't make sense to try to use the setLabelFor(...) method twice on a single label.

Why do you even have two radio buttons? The purpose of a radio button is to have two states on/off, selected/unselected. So having two radio buttons with "Yes/No" doesn't make sense. You should only have a single label describing what the button is used for.

Comment: setLabelFor() I am using just to specify the radio button belongs to which label and why I cannot use same label for two ?

Comment: @Nidhi, Did you read the API? The setLabelFor(...) method is used to invoke requestFocus() on the specified component. If you attempt to specify two component how would this code work. Also the method uses "set" (not "add") so whenever you invoke the method you replace the old property. This is the way all "setter" methods work.

Comment: The purpose of radio buttons is to allow multiple choices. Aren't you thinking of checkboxes (which would indeed be more relevant in a yes/no scenario)?